# How to set a long as hex in Spring XML config

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.SomeThing">
    <property name="longValue">
        <bean class="java.lang.Long">
            <constructor-arg value="0x0418a14372d4186eL" type="long"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But this results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'java.lang.Long#19190b75' defined in file [/apollo/env/path/to/config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
```

Comment: This works as well: `<property name="longValue" value="0x0418a14372d4186e"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `factory-method` parameter of `<bean>`:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.SomeThing">
    <property name="longValue">
        <bean class="java.lang.Long" factory-method="decode">
            <constructor-arg value="0x0418a14372d4186" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(Note the lack of the "L" suffix.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Java `@Configuration`?

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public SomeThing someThing() {
        final SomeThing bean = new SomeThing();
        bean.set(Long.parseLong("0418a14372d4186e", 16));
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SPeL should work

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.SomeThing">
    <property name="longValue" value="#{0x0418a14372d4186eL}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This one isnt working for me :  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{0x0418a14372d4136eL}"

Comment: did you forget to add the #? because the SPeL clearly parses hex